# Accessing Buttons in a frame Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Currently this is part of a program:

```
self.tabs = Notebook(root)
self.tabs.grid(column=0, row=0)   
self.frame1 = Frame()
self.frame2 = Frame()
self.frame3 = Frame()
self.frame4 = Frame()
self.frame5 = Frame()
self.frame6 = Frame()
self.framemain = Frame()
self.framemain.grid(column=1, row=0)

def buttonCreate(frameCount):
    buttonhatsforward = Button(self.frame1, image=self.forwardrender, command=select.buttonHatsForwardClicked).grid(column=3, row=0)
    button1 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button1.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)
    button2 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button2.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
    button3 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button3.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
    button4 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button4.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
    button5 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button5.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=W)

    button6 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button6.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=W)
    button7 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button7.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)
    button8 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button8.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=W)
    button9 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button9.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
    button10 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button10.grid(column=4, row=2, sticky=W)

    button11 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button11.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=W)
    button12 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button12.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)
    button12 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button13.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)
    button13 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button13.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
    button14 = Button(frameCount, text = "hello")
    button14.grid(column=4, row=3, sticky=W)

buttonCreate(self.frame1)
buttonCreate(self.frame2)
buttonCreate(self.frame3)
buttonCreate(self.frame4)
buttonCreate(self.frame5)
buttonCreate(self.frame6)


self.tab1 = self.tabs.add(self.frame1, text="tab1")
self.tab2 = self.tabs.add(self.frame2, text="tab2")
self.tab3 = self.tabs.add(self.frame3, text="tab3")
self.tab4 = self.tabs.add(self.frame4, text="tab4")
self.tab5 = self.tabs.add(self.frame5, text="tab5")
self.tab6 = self.tabs.add(self.frame6, text="tab6")
```

What this does is make a frame, add buttons to it and then add it to some tabs. The problem is that when I do `self.button1.config(text="cookie")` for example, it refers to the last frame. How can I make it so I can access every button separately?

Comment: There's not enough code to go on. Is `buttonCreate` part of a class? It doesn't have a `self` parameter.

Comment: Please give a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Done. The `buttonCreate` is what I use to add buttons to each frame, as you can see below `buttonCreate(self.frame1)` adds it to the first frame, `buttonCreate(self.frame2)` adds it to the second frame etc. Ideally, I want to be able to control each button with something like `self.frame1.button1.config(text = "hello")`.

Comment: I am quite confident that your example is neither complete nor minimal...

Comment: This is a basic issue involving function scope. Look into how to return objects from a function and save references to those objects.

Answer (score 0):

@TigerhawkT3, thank you for making me think outside the box. I took a quick shower, then I realised I can do: `return(button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, button13, button14)`, then modify my `buttonCreate` function to `a = buttonCreate(self.frame1)`, and finally `a[2].configure(text="cake", compound=LEFT)`.

While returning 14 buttons is not a good idea, I'll keep working on it to make it slimmer and neater. Shame you didn't leave an answer, I would have upvoted you. :(